# Chef provisioning with Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, provisioning, infrastructure

[Chef provisioning](https://github.com/chef/chef-provisioning) offers a library for creating machines and infrastructures idempotently in Chef.

There is also a [driver for using Vagrant](https://github.com/chef/chef-provisioning-vagrant).

With a few changes I managed to get a simple example working on my local laptop. I put code below in Ruby file `vagrant_linux.rb` and then run it with `chef-client -z vagrant_linux.rb`.

```
require 'chef/provisioning/vagrant_driver'
with_driver 'vagrant'

with_machine_options :vagrant_options => {
  'vm.box' => 'ubuntu/trusty64'#,
},:vagrant_config => <<EOF
    config.vm.provider 'virtualbox' do |v|
      v.memory = 4096
      v.cpus = 2
    end
EOF
machine 'mario' do
  converge true
end
```

When I create a Chef recipe based on this example, upload that to my Chef server and then apply to a node, this consistently fails with message

```
[2016-06-20T20:16:36+02:00] ERROR: machine[mario] (ok-test::default line 99) had an error: RuntimeError: vagrant up mario --provider virtualbox failed!
STDOUT:
STDERR:Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

Vagrant is attempting to interface with the UI in a way that requires
a TTY. Most actions in Vagrant that require a TTY have configuration
switches to disable this requirement. Please do that or run Vagrant
with TTY.
```

Google search shows that this is common issue for which there does not seem to be a good/working fix or workaround.

This makes me wonder if I am trying to do something I shouldn't because it is not supported and there is a better way to do it.

Vagrant is of course a tool that runs on local laptop. It is not typically used on a server.

What should I use to do provisioning of simple VirtualBox machines on a server?

Comment: `test-kitchen` actually works well for this, and it's what I use to get a provisioned scratch VM, even if I'm not testing a cookbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chef Provisioning is no longer a project you should probably start new work based on, see https://coderanger.net/provisioning/ for details. As mentioned in a comment, Test Kitchen is the right tool to use for setting up development and testing VMs either locally via Vagrant or using one of the various cloud plugins.